# Custom model validation for many to many field in django

Tags: django, validation, django-models

Hi there I have a model like this:

```
class Team(models.Model):
    owner = models.ForeignKey(User)
    members = models.ManyToManyField(User)
```

Now One Owner can have multiple teams but a particular member will only belong to one team. So let's say if there is a team with member `John`, user can't create team with the same member again.

For that, I am trying to add custom model field validation:

```
def clean_fields(self, exclude=None):
        super(MentorTeam, self).clean_fields(exclude=exclude)
        self.candidates # This returns error because the team instance is not saved yet.
```

How can I do this validation?

Answer (score 0):

By definition, `ManyToMany` relationship means that a member can belong to many teams.

What you should do is do a ForeignKey to `Team` from `User` model:

```
class User(models.Model):
    team = models.ForeignKey(Team, related_name='members')
    ...
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: Is this a good architecture? If an admin wants to team and assign members easily, how can he do that? It seems there will be a lot of db query involved?

Comment: Another problem I see is `team` attribute can't be empty on `User` model and the `owner` attribute on `Team` model can't be empty too. So How can I create instances on these?